# Random int stream to generic linked list

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, java-stream, secure-random

In a coding exercise I am working on, I am trying to generate 25 random integers and insert them into a linked list using a function which sorts them.  I understand how to do these tasks separately, but I would like to try to do them as a stream.  This is the code I wrote to set this up with a sample list to make sure the insertSorted function works.

#### Node.java

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T data;
    Node<T> nextNode;

    Node(T data) {
        this(data, null);
    };

    Node(T data, Node<T> nextNode){
        this.data = data;
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    };

    void setNext(Node<T> next){
        nextNode = next;
    }

}
```

#### SortedList.java

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

class SortedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private Node<T> firstNode;
    private Node<T> lastNode;
    private String name;

    SortedList(String listName){
        name = listName;
        firstNode = lastNode = null;
    }

    void insertSorted(T item){
        if(isEmpty()){
            lastNode = new Node<T>(item);
            firstNode = lastNode;
        } else if(firstNode.data.compareTo(item) > 0){
            firstNode = new Node<T>(item, firstNode);
        }
        else {
            Node<T> compareNode = firstNode;
            while(compareNode.nextNode != null
            && compareNode.nextNode.data.compareTo(item) < 0){
                compareNode = compareNode.nextNode;
            }
            Node<T> itemNode = new Node<T>(item, compareNode.nextNode);
            compareNode.setNext(itemNode);
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmpty() { return firstNode == null; }

    void print() {
        if (isEmpty()){
            System.out.printf("Empty %s%n", name);
            return;
        }

        System.out.printf("%s is: ", name);
        Node<T> current = firstNode;

        while (current != null){
            System.out.printf("%s ", current.data);
            current = current.nextNode;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

#### Main.java

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        // sample example
        SortedList<Integer> sample = new SortedList<>("sample list");
        sample.insertSorted(84);
        sample.insertSorted(65);
        sample.insertSorted(134);
        sample.insertSorted(102);
        sample.insertSorted(954);
        sample.insertSorted(755);

        sample.print();
    }
}
```

I know that I can generate an array of random ints from a stream with code such as this:

```
int[] arr = new SecureRandom().ints(25, 0, 100).toArray();
```

How might I contain a random int stream within the SortedList object above using the insertSorted method?

Comment: List<Integer> sorted = new SecureRandom().ints(25, 0, 100).boxed().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @ravthiru it’s likely more efficient to do `.sorted() .boxed()` instead, to let the sorting work on primitive data (if the underlying implementation isn’t smart enough to do the swapping on its own).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SortedList::insertSorted(T t)` looks like a `Consumer<T>`, so you can use stream functions that accept a consumer as an argument, like `.forEach(...)`:

```
new SecureRandom().ints(25, 0, 100)
    .boxed()
    .forEach( sample::insertSorted );
```

As @Holger mentions in the comments, `.boxed()` is not necessary.

```
new SecureRandom().ints(25, 0, 100)
    .forEach( sample::insertSorted );
```

I've verified this on Java8 and Java9, so now I'm not sure when it was ever necessary, or what changed when to make it so.

Comment: `.boxed()` is obsolete. `new SecureRandom().ints(25, 0, 100) .forEach(sample::insertSorted);` will already do the job.

Comment: Is it possible to use the insertSorted method before creating the sample?  I mean something like this: `SortedList<Integer> sample = new SecureRandom().ints(25, 0, 100) .forEach(SortedList::insertSorted);`

Comment: You would need to create a [`Collector<T,A,R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) that creates the container and accumulates the elements.   Then you would write `SortedList<Integer> sample = new SecureRandom().ints(25, 0, 100).collect( your_collector );`. To create the collector, you can start with `Collector.of(SortedList::new, SortedList::insertSorted, your_custom_combiner)`, of course implementing your own custom combiner function/lambda to merge partial lists if a parallel stream is being collected.